# How to Publish DNS Record of a Subdomain?

Tags: dns, subdomain

I'm trying to understand how to publish the DNS of a subdomain.  For example, if I have mydomain.com which points to IP 444.444.33.344. I added an A Record to this domain with host = "meetings" and IP 222.222.32.332.  The domain resolves to mydomain.com @ 444.444.33.344 and the subdomain, meetings.mydomain.com points to (resolves to) 222.222.32.332.

However, if I use mxlookup to check the subdomain meetings.mydomain.com, the results state that the DNS record is not found.  I'm trying to understand how to have the DNS record found and show that it resolves to 222.222.32.332.

In the end, I'm trying to use Let's Encrypt for a SSL certificate on the subdomain which points to a bigbluebutton server.  I know this is a very newbie questions so may just a point in the right direction to research would help.

Comment: This depends on your DNS hosting provider.

Comment: 444.444.33.344 is a strange IP address. `mxlookup` only checks MX records, not A, if I understand it right. Try a tool like `dig` to check the A record.

Answer (score 0):

A records need to be fully qualified, your A record may need to be entered as meetings.mydomain.com.

Comment: It doesn't depend on the record type... but it does depend a lot on the DNS management tool. Often this is the case, but often it's the opposite and trying to qualify the name results in a _double_ suffix.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for DNS servers to proceed changes. It depends on your provider (mostly up to 24 hours I think).
Also you can try a DNS response with the nslookup tool in cmd.